# KinectRegion namespace using windows app store

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, kinect

I have to create Windows store app using Kinect. I want to handle gesture with Kinect.
I followed lot of tutorials but i can't create a KinectRegion with XAML.

Here's my pastbin :

http://pastebin.com/avBtPJ1j

```
<Page
    x:Class="Projet11._0.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Projet11._0"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:k="Microsoft.Kinect.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <k:KinectRegion> 
        // My interface using XAML
        </k:KinectRegion>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I have this error : " Unknown type 'KinectRegion' in namespace XML : "Microsoft.Kinect.Xaml.Controls" ".

I already add the references :
-Microsoft Kinect Toolkit Input
-Microsoft Kinect VisualGestureBuild
-Microsoft Kinect Xaml Controls.

I use Kinect V2 and SDK 2.0

I know that KinectRegion is IN "Microsoft.Kinect.Xaml.Controls", but he can't find it.

MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.xaml.controls.kinectregion.aspx
and with toolkit namespace :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectregion.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.xaml.controls.aspx

Any idea ? I tried lot of namespace ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have the project targeted to the wrong DLLs for the solution that you are building.

For instance, if you built using Windows WPF or Windows 8.0 or Windows 8.1. There are different versions of the DLLs that you need to target. Try removing the references and re-adding.

Answer (score 0):

I Had this problem before.
It's just too hard to give you a solution just like this as it varies and you should learn why.
Just go to the MSDN Blog to this tutorial (specifically at the minute 13:00 ): [Programming Kinect for Windows v2 E03](http://channel9.msdn.com/series/Programming-Kinect-for-Windows-v2/03)

here is where they are adding the kinect user viewer and the kinect region to the metro app and explaining the best way to do so.
Best of luck.